# How to corrupt and repair MBR correctly?

Tags: grub

I have tried to corrupt MBR with this command on CentOS 7

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sda bs=446 count=1
```

As far as i know, the boot sector has 512 bytes length, the first 446 bytes is boot loader code, the rest is partition table.

After booting in Resecure Mode, `/dev/sda1` is mounted on `/mnt` and `chroot /mnt`, i used `grub2-install` to repair boot loader on `/dev/sda` but it didn't success to boot again.

What point did i miss?

Comment: You missed taking a backup before intentionally breaking it.

Comment: /dev/sda is the disk. You're talking about MBR and partion table. therefore you shouldn't be talking about mounting /dev/sda to /mnt. that should be /dev/sda1 etc.

Comment: @A.B That is a typo, as the OP mentioning he mounts them.  Good point though.

Comment: Is Grub even in your MBR? Modern PCs often boot via UEFI. What was the original content of the first 446 bytes of `/dev/sda`?

Comment: @Gilles 
https://pastebin.com/RMgpuskX
I copy this from 'fdisk /dev/sda', in the original VM. How can you read this Hex code? btw

Comment: @FederalReserve I can't read it, but programs such as `fdisk` and `file` can. `file` says “DOS/MBR boot sector” and `GRUB` does appear in the dump so you are booting via MBR, not UEFI.

Comment: You should post the actual error message you get when the boot does not succeed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After chrooting, but before running `grub2-install`, you should have checked if `/boot/grub/device.map` exists or not. Normally, `grub2-install` creates it if it does not already exist, and it tries to guess which Linux device corresponds to which BIOS/GRUB disk identifier. If this mapping is wrong, you'll get strange results.

Unless your system is very special, if you are telling BIOS to boot from the disk that is `/dev/sda`, then `/boot/grub/device.map` should have this line in it:

```
(hd0) /dev/sda
```

If the device.map file did not exist when you ran `grub2-install`, it would have had to guess the mapping between Linux device names and BIOS/GRUB disk identifiers. Sometimes `grub2-install` can guess wrong. So if `/boot/grub/device.map` does not exist, you should create it with the correct information before running `grub2-install` to ensure successful repair.

If the `/boot/grub/device.map` file exists but has wrong information, you should fix it before running `grub2-install`.

Now you should again boot into rescue mode, chroot and then check the `/boot/grub/device.map` file, then run `grub2-install /dev/sda`.

---

Another possibility:

When you overwrite the first 446 bytes of the MBR, it includes the signature bytes that are used as disk UUID on MBR-partitioned disks. If the GRUB configuration is using the disk UUID to select the GRUB "root" partition, the UUID will now be different. Your distribution should have a command that can be used to easily rebuild the GRUB configuration file.

In Debian-style systems, it is probably `update-grub`.

In RedHat-style systems (Fedora, CentOS etc.), it might be `grub2-mkconfig > /boot/grub/grub.cfg` or similar.

---

The message: **FATAL: INT18: BOOT FAILURE** is not related to Grub at all, but a problem with VirtualBox.

Apparently VirtualBox checks the partition table to verify that a partition has been marked as active, and if there is no active partition, it reports an error instead of even trying to load & run the MBR code.

This check is unnecessary for GRUB, because if GRUB has been installed to the MBR, it will take control of the boot process regardless of which partition is marked as active.

Source: https://neosmart.net/wiki/fatal-int18-boot-failure/

Having the installation media image still inserted in the virtual CD-ROM drive might also do it, at least with older VirtualBox versions:

https://www.dedoimedo.com/computers/fedora-fatal-18.html

Comment: I tried to create `device.map` in both `/boot/grub` and `/boot/grub2`
After that, i generated config using `grub2-mkconfig` to both `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` and `/boot/grub2/grub.cfg` 

Then executed `grub2-install /dev/sda` again. It still got error when i select boot from **Local Hard Drive**

Comment: The error is **FATAL: INIT18 : BOOT FAILURE**

Comment: Looks like a VirtualBox error message. Updated my answer.

Comment: OMG, thank you very much, i tested this lab for a week and didn't know what goes wrong. I should Google the Error before, didn't think it was VirtualBox. T_T

Comment: See? Posting the **actual error message** helps a lot!